# How do I finish of this SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

It works but what I would like is to list username, first name, last name not all but I've tried JOIN and isn't seeming to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

MY DB:

http://gyazo.com/eb13cd68440d20719ce0783018cb9828

Comment: What table is your authors details stored on? Can we get the table structure?

Comment: Please provide sample table and sample output

Comment: @ullas http://gyazo.com/eb13cd68440d20719ce0783018cb9828

Comment: post your schema so that we can give a precise answer for if its working and only for listing instead of select * use select username,firstname,lastname from table

Comment: @NaveenThally Basically I need to get the first name and last name from the table members to join with comments

Comment: @sally post the schema of both the tables so that we can help

Comment: @NaveenThally COMMENTS http://gyazo.com/8dbf74d91bfde5e5e9f5da7494d75e05 AND                            MEMBERS: http://gyazo.com/1b56b076f23dc594e0175d7c444779ff

Comment: try the below one i have not tested it                           select Username,first_name,last_name,count(*) as totalc from member m,comments c where m.memberID=c.memberID  
group by c.member_id order by totalc desc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT
      M.Username,
      M.first_name,
      M.Last_name,
      COUNT(1) AS num_comments

  FROM members AS M
  INNER JOIN comments AS C
      ON C.memberID = M.memberID

  GROUP BY
      C.memberID
  ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

This matches the Member to all their comments, groups by the member to get the count of comments for the users, orders by the count starting highest first, then returns the first result.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting * (ALL) just use `SELECT table.username, table.firstname, table.lastname [...]`.

You can leave out the `table.` if all information is stored in your comments table. If not, adjust accordingly. In that case you'll also need to Join the comments table with the table where the rest of the information is stored.

Edit:

```
SELECT m.username, m.first_name, m.last_name FROM members m, comments c WHERE m.MemberID = c.MemberID AND c.author = (select max(author) from comments)
```

Comment: Yeah I am unsure how to join members to comments and make it work basically.

Comment: Just a warning, author is a varchar column, running `MAX` over it will return whoever comes last alphabetically, not the person with the most comments.

Comment: I took it that his query from the OP worked (he says so), but yeah in that case the answer below is the better one. I didn't look out for the types, my mistake. PS: Before somebody says I am using deprecated syntax, yes I know. I prefer the ANSI-98 for short queries